# CakePHP Flash messages is not showing because of cache

Tags: php, session, cakephp, caching

**Updated:**

**Problem:**

Flash messages is not showing.

When i am using Active/Deactivate/Add/Edit functionality in my application then a Flash messages should show but not showing.

When i am clearing my Browser cache it is working fine at first time (Flash messages is showing). 
but now again i am using Active/Deactivate/Add/Edit the flash messages are not showing.
again When i am clearing my Browser cache it is working fine.

I figure out Cache problem.
But how could i get rid from this Cache problem.

**Previous problem:**

I have find out the Cache Problem.

I have a critical problem. **CakePHP** Flash messages are not showing in Chrome,Fire Fox browser on One PC but same flash messages are showing in Chrome, Fire Fox browsers on other PC and Also JavaScript is unable on both browsers.

What could the issue ?

I have checked on other 20 PC, Flash messages are working fine in both browser.

Comment: So clear cache after SAVE ,EDIT operation , check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me..

in AppController :

```
function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    $this->response->disableCache();
}
```

Comment: This approach excluded all view cache, the same could be achieved by removing the cache helper

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use the cache helper.

Here's what he says [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#marking-non-cached-content-in-views):

> **Marking Non-Cached Content in Views**
>
> There will be times when you don’t want an entire view cached. For example, certain parts of the page may look different whether a user is currently logged in or browsing your site as a guest.
>
> To indicate blocks of content that are not to be cached, wrap them in

`<!--nocache--> <!--/nocache-->` like so:

```
<!--nocache-->
<?php if ($this->Session->check('User.name')): ?>
   Welcome, <?php echo h($this->Session->read('User.name')); ?>.
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $this->Html->link('Login', 'users/login'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--/nocache-->
```

In your case:

```
<!--nocache-->
$this->Session->setFlash('My text here');
<!--/nocache-->
```

Comment: Thnx for your ans.. :)